# How to resolve unknown Python reference to dependency 'mpl_toolkits' in PyCharm?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dependencies, pycharm

**UPDATE:**
When i run it without the `cmap=cm.hsv` call i get an empty plot
with the error: 
`.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py:1673: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide for n in normals])`

[image]

Unresolved references for mpl_toolkits and cm 
(am betting cm is from mpl_toolkits)
I have tried [Invalidating Caches & Restarting (as well as manually readding the path to mpl_toolkits)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-unresolved-references-with-remote-interpreter) 
with no success.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadnt imported cm
`from matplotlib import cm`
and i needed to import mplot3d like 
`from mplot3d import Axes3D` instead of 
`from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`
My data was not ranged correctly too (why nothing was showing). Needed to range form -10 to 10, i had left out the minus sign.

Comment: Mind if I ask how you got mplot3d in the first place.  Doesn't show up for me at all.  Thanks.

Comment: sorry @bob.sacamento i only just saw your comment. this was a while ago, but as you can see, the packages i was using are shown in the screenshot. so i hope that helps if your still in need of it.