# PyCharm 3.4.1: Unresolved reference 'map'

Tags: python, pycharm

As we know, `map` is a Python built-in function.

I use PyCharm 3.4.1 currently, and it reports an

> Unresolved reference 'map'

in my code:

```py
a = map(int, [1,2,3])
```

where the map word was with red waved underscore, and shows this tip of message.

[image]

I've been reading about the question: [PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code)

And did *File | Invalidate Caches... and restarting PyCharm helps.*

But problem still unsolved.

---

For more info, I'm working on a Django 1.6 object. The project interpreter is as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the point myself:

Pycharm generates a file `builtins.py` for code prompt.

It's path is probably under:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.4.1\helpers\python-skeletons\builtins.py`

Randomly choose a built-in function, click it with `Ctrl` key, then this file is open in PyCharm.

Then I see the error, but still without knowing how and when it happens:

[image]

I see the multiline comment block was closed incorrectly.

I manually fixed it, and everything goes well!