# Unresolved Reference in virtual environment Pycharm/Tastypie/Django

Tags: django, virtualbox, virtualenv, tastypie

I installed tastypie in my virtual env using sudo pip install django-tastypie, but when I do

```
#api.py
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
```

Pycharm states that tastypie is an unresolved reference. 
Even in my INSTALLED_APPS settings, it states that tastypie is unresolved

I've been reading about the question: [[PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code][1])  but Project Interpreters is blank when I open it.

And did File | Invalidate Caches... and restarted PyCharm

But problem is still unsolved.

```
(kp1)vagrant@precise64:~/development/kp$ sudo pip install django-tastypie
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-tastypie in  
/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/kp1/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I was wondering how I can let Pycharm know where the tastypie is since it i

```
(kp1)vagrant@precise64:~/development/kp$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tastypie
>>>
```

No error comes up when this happens so I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to download Tastypie on your own system as well as in the VM. -_-