# Pycharm Unresolved References for previously working imports (requests)

Tags: python, python-requests, pycharm, python-3.4

When attempting to import a module from a package, PyCharm Complains about unresolved references.  The project interpreter is configured correctly (I've tried virtualenv's and non), and the code runs correctly as well.
[image]

Adding in the explicit module name in the import seems to calm PyCharm down and let me follow the reference to Session
[image]

I have tried 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' several times to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a bug in PyCharm, following the advice here fixed my references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665019/3205089

> If none of the other solutions work for you, try (backing up) and deleting your ~/.PyCharm40 folder, then reopening PyCharm. This will kill all your preferences as well.
>
> On Mac you want to delete ~/Library/Caches/Pycharm40 and ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm40.
>
> And on Windows: C:\Users\$USER.PyCharm40.

I also deleted Pycharm50 folders.

Comment: do you have an __init__ by the way? in the working folder?

Comment: Yeah, the folder hand an __init__.py.  Blowing away pycharm prefs and caches fixed it.