# unresolved attribute "Column" in class "SQLAlchemy"

Tags: python, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

i use pycharm 5.0 and python3.5.And i download all the liarbry by the build-in function of pycharm(setting-project-project interpreter-"+").other libraries appear well,but some problems happens to flask-SQLAlchemy.

i import flask-SQLAlchemy successfully.however,pycharm remind me that "unresolved attribute reference 'Column' in class'SQLAlchemy'"."unresolved attribute reference 'relationship' in class 'SQLAlchemy'" and so on.

I  have try some ways ,but they didn't work.for example:1.restart 2.remove and redownload 3.refresh the cache.which mention in [PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code?rq=1)

code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, session, url_for, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
import os
from wtforms.validators import data_required


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hard to guess string'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =\
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True


bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role %r>' % self.name


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

how can i  solve this problem?

Comment: sth confuses me ......I  find that the attribute "Column" 's location is in G:\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py,but the class 'SQLAlchemy' is in G:\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py, and i didn't find any attribute in class 'SQLAlchemy' 's  source code .

Comment: Does your code run? That's the important thing. I took a look at the source for flask_sqlalchemy, it looks like it uses some magic to be compatible with the base sqlalchemy lib that PyCharm might not correctly detect.

Comment: it can runs.But i want to know the way how python handle this ,that is the relationship between extention lib and origin lib,how do they connect

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 20):

The constructor of the `flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy` class calls [`_include_sqlalchemy`](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/2.4.4/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L72), which attaches all attributes from `sqlalchemy` and `sqlalchemy.orm` to its instances.

This is only done at runtime and not detected by PyCharm's code inspection.

It would require `flask_sqlalchemy` to use a more standard way of importing those attributes, like `from sqlalchemy import *`. But this would import the attributes into the `flask_sqlalchemy` module instead of each instance of `SQLAlchemy` and thus change the way they're accessed.

I'm not a Python or SQLAlchemy expert and won't judge whether this is good design or not but you could open an issue on https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy and discuss it there.

Comment: Per [this comment](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/999#issuecomment-917046523) from the maintainer it doesn't look like they will be added soon.

Answer (score 9):

here is what I do.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from typing import Callable


class MySQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):  # Or you can add the below code on the SQLAlchemy directly if you think to modify the package code is acceptable.
    Column: Callable  # Use the typing to tell the IDE what the type is.
    String: Callable
    Integer: Callable


db = MySQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))  # The message will not show: Unresolved attribute reference 'Column' for class 'SQLAlchemy' 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


def create_test_data():
    db.create_all()
    test_user = User(name='Frank')  # I add __init__, so it will not show you ``Unexpected argument``
    db.session.add(test_user)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is best practice or not, but it definitely reduces a bit of an annoyance, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same problem just now.

In short if I just hit Run the code runs with exit code 0 even is PyCharm shows **Unresolved attribute reference**
but for anyone who might make the same mistake as I did before simply hitting Run:

This is the code that I was writing and it showed 'Unresolved attribute reference 'Column' for class 'SQLAlchemy'' also for eg. 'Unresolved attribute reference 'Integer' for class 'SQLAlchemy' '.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///new-books-collection.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = 
False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Books(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)


db.create_all()
```

My problem was that I hovered over Column and Integer and clicked Add method Column() to class SQLAlchemy. Also the same with Integer.

From that moment TypeErrors came up for me because it created these empty methods in `__init__.py` of SQLAlchemy.

To solve this I used `pip install flask_sqlalchemy --upgrade` and `pip install flask_sqlalchemy`. And **did not Add methods again.** It still showed Unresolved attribute reference, but the code ran with exit code 0 and the database was created, with the right data inside.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Check the version of flask_sqlalchemy in your pycharm or environment.
i had same problem ,the easiest solution

```
pip install flask_sqlalchemy --upgrade
```

100% its gone work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).