# Unresolved references pycharm django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've looked at other threads but I still don't know how the hell I'm supposed to resolve this issue. I've provided screenshots, I hope they are of use to you guys.

http://s11.postimg.org/6mpv39sab/screen_1_for_stackoverflow.png

http://s7.postimg.org/x62k3lhgr/screen_2_for_stackoverflow.png

Comment: Just to clarify again: I've tried the steps the that were in the other threads.

Comment: You're already inside social, just `import views`

Comment: would you also tell us what exactly?

Comment: You should read this http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/. Then come back and edit your question accordingly

Comment: I did the import views but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @ProfHase85 pycharm cannot find the references to my views and models.

Comment: If it helps, I got pycharm version 5.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is due to a caching problem in PyCharm. Go to `File --> Invalidate caches` and restart PyCharm.

Related - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code).

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem for me.

Comment: I tried everything on the thread you suggested and none of it really works. There was one suggestion which was weird: where you reload the paths but that only does it for one file.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering I got it to work (by luck) by just deleting the idea files and invalidating caches (well, atleast i think).