# calling a function before its definition in python

Tags: python

Is there any way to call a function before its definition.

```
def Insert(value):
    """place value at an available leaf, then bubble up from there"""
    heap.append(value)
    BubbleUp(len(heap) - 1)

def BubbleUp(position):
    print 'something'
```

This code shows "unresolved reference BubbleUp"

Comment: No, you can't do that. Your code is fine though because `BubbleUp` is not being called before it is defined.

Comment: This code _should_ work, since `BubbleUp` is not called when `Insert` is declared, but when it's actually _called_.

Comment: you are not calling either calls in this code, if you called `Insert` after both definitions then you'd be fine.

Comment: Also, what is "unresolved reference"? Did you get a `NameError`? If this is a warning/error in your IDE: What IDE are you using?

Comment: The `def` line is evaluated at import time, the actual call only when the function is called. So, `BubbleUp` is defined then. But if are using an IDE it might get confused with that and shows an error.

Comment: Your code is alright as already explained by others, now... if you're using pycharm... could it be your error related to this? [pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code)

Answer (score 6):

The code here doesn't show anything, least of all an error, because neither of the functions is called. What matters is the location of the call to `Insert`, and as long as it comes after `BubbleUp` (and why wouldn't it), there is no issue. Function *definitions* don't execute the function body, so you can define functions in whatever order you like, as long as you refrain from calling any of them until all necessary functions are defined.