# python why doesnt this work

Tags: python, pycharm

```
from math import factorial
import math
def get_bernoulli(n):
    b = 0
    sum = 0
    for k in range (0, n-1):
        part = (factorial(n)) / factorial(k) * factorial(n+1 - k)))*b
        sum += part
        b = -(1/n+1)*sum
```

pycharm is complaining about n k and b. It displays unsolved reference.  what does this means?

Comment: You never call `get_bernoulli` function. There's also no return statement, so what you are "getting"?

Comment: Related: [PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code) ?

Comment: Is this the full code?

Comment: No return statement is fine. The function will just return None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's play count the parentheses in this line:

```
part = (factorial(n)) / factorial(k) * factorial(n+1 - k)))*b
```

- 4x - "("
- 6x - ")"