# Python lxml module lets me import etree in Python 3.2 but not in Python 3.4

Tags: python, lxml

I have used lxml's etree class successfully in 32-bit Python 3.2 using `from lxml import etree`, but I just installed it for 64-bit Python 3.5 using `pip install lxml`, and PyCharm calls etree an unresolved reference.  PyCharm's interpreter settings window tells me that I am using version 3.2.3 of lxml in Python 3.2, and version 3.7.2 in Python 3.5.

I rely on XML parsing extensively in my scripts.  How can I import etree from the latest version of lxml, or is there something else I'm supposed to do to get similar functionality from that module?

This question is a duplicate of one posted in April of 2016, but that question and similar ones were never answered.  If I missed a question that had as answer, I would appreciate a link to that question.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:  It appears that lxml does work with Python 3.5!  After Dragon asked if I had actually tested it in Python or was merely relying on PyCharm flagging etree as unresolved, I tried I was merely relying on PyCharm.  I tried this script:

```
from lxml import etree

if __name__=='__main__':
    print ("This is a print statement.")

    try:
        x = etree.fromstring("This is not XML")
    except Exception as ex:
        print (str(ex))
```

The output of this was:

```
C:\Python35\python.exe C:/Misc/lxmltest.py
This is a print statement.
Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1 (<string>, line 1)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I was expecting an unresolved reference error.  Instead, the error message shows that etree.fromstring() was successfully called.

Many thanks to Dragon for his (her?) help

Comment: Which OS?
Do you get error messages from running the Python code as well as PyCharm warning you? What, exactly, are these error messages?
Have you tried downgrading? `pip uninstall lxml`; `pip install lxml==2.3`
Try working in a virtualenv to isolate yourself from any brokenness that your default python install might have?
Good luck -- diagnosing these sorts of issues can be a complete nightmare!

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  Being primarily a C# developer, I was assuming that PyCharm knew everything there is to know about every module and class I use.  That appears to be false.  I wrote a little test program, and the durn thing worked!  I'll edit the original post to show my test.

Comment: Quickly searching around suggests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code might help fix the underlying problem.