# Unresolved reference 'models'

Tags: python, django

I am writing custom template tag, and the error occurs that "Unresolved reference 'models'"
the following is my blog_tags.py.

```
from django import template

from .models import Post

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def total_posts():
    return Post.published.count()
```

And my directory tree is as followed

```
blog/
  __init__.py 
  models.py 
  ...
  templatetags/
     __init__.py
     blog_tags.py
```

And i do have a Post class in my Models.

And when i click the prompt by pycharm "install package Post", after finishing installed it, the error disappear.
I wonder do i have to do the same, which is install the package by the IDE, every time when i want to write a custom tag evolved with class in my Models?

Comment: Try this: `from blog.models import Post`.

Comment: `from ..models import Post` if you want to make a relative import. `.` means from the same folder, so it is looking in `templatetags` where there is no `models.py`.

Comment: @nik_m I tried blog.models but it doesn't work, however the  ..models worked

Comment: @jojo Thank you it, ..model worked, and i do learn from it!

Answer (score 5):

If I'm interpreting your project structure correctly, your `models` module is located in a parent package relative to `blog_tags`. Accessing `.models` would try to find the module inside your `templatetags` package.

Try to change your import to this instead:

```
from ..models import Post
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is Django and as in Django circular imports can be an issue, consider dynamically loading the model:

for django 1.7+ use the [application registry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#module-django.apps):

```
from django.apps import apps
Post = apps.get_model('blog', 'Post')
```

for earlier versions:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
Post = get_model('blog', 'Post')
```

**Note:** This only works if 'blog' is an installed app.

Comment: Sorry but what is circular import?

Answer (score 0):

import your models with `app` namespace instead of relative import, so that the standard structure is maintained.

```
from django import template

# blog is your app name
from blog.models import Post

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def total_posts():
    return Post.published.count()
```

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code) unresolved error issue related to pycharm in django projects

Comment: I've tried with blog.models, but it won't work. and with ..models worked

Comment: i support @jojo 's answer