# pycharm is showing error in module import resolution even if program is working fine

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new in Python and pycharm ide.
I have created one of my own module and importing it in another python file.
Both of my python files are in same direcotary and parent directory has been made Sources Root directory.

Now my program is working fine but pycharm ide is showing error in import statement and on hover prompting no such module.

I am not sure if i am doing something wrong please let me know what is the proper way to import a module.

here is my project structure -
Main.py is importing Greeting.py and getting error.test is a root directory.
[image: Main.py]

[image: Greeting.py]

Comment: Can you share the code/error snippet and directory tree?

Comment: try closing and opening again.....and activate your virtual environment if you have not done already

Comment: Known problem: invalidate you cache and set project root in preferences

Comment: @Arseniy please elaborate in detail.

Comment: @prashantsindhu https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html

Comment: @Arseniy thanks, it solves problem.

Answer (score 8):

For my case, I had my problem was not resolved by invalidating the cache,
My problem was with the directories (packages) and the root directory.
Here was my structure.

```
MyApp:
|
|----my_first_app
|--------my_first_app_files
|--------my_first_app_directories
|----my_second_app
|--------my_second_app_files
|--------my_second_app_directories
```

So what I did on my editor was I right clicked `app:>mark directory as:>sources root`

*Referrence*

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28696003/6687699)

Answer (score 3):

invalidate cache and restart resolved the problem.

[jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html](https://jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html)