# Pycharm says unresolved error when import but the code execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a issue with Pycharm, that shows an error on importing local modules, even though it works.

[image]

The working code for `import` is

```
from response_generator import core
```

Pycharm suggests

```
from .response_generator import core
```

When executing what pycharm suggest. Error received is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.response_generator'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Anyone got a fix on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code)

Comment: `from .response_generator import core` you include in your `__init__.py`. Then you can use `from response_generator import core` in your code.