# Importing a module from same directory 'unresolved reference'

Tags: python, pycharm, setuptools

**Update:** found [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code/37231130)

---

How can I import MyClass from classmodule?

directory structure:

```
/project
  /datagenerator
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    classmodule.py
    setup.py
```

Ran the program: `python datagenerator`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "datagenerator\__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .classmodule import MyClass
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

**__main__.py** importing `MyClass`

```
import sys
from .classmodule import MyClass
from .funcmodule import my_function


def main():
    print('in main')
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    print('count of args :: {}'.format(len(args)))
    for arg in args:
        print('passed argument :: {}'.format(arg))
    my_function('hello world')
    my_object = MyClass('Thomas')
    my_object.say_name()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried this:

```
from classmodule import MyClass
```

Even though `__main__.py` and classmodule are in the same directory there is unresolved reference

```
Unresolved reference 'classmodule'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code)

Answer (score 0):

Invalid `import` syntax in your code. Instead, try this:

```
from classmodule import MyClass
from funcmodule import my_function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file structure should look like:

directory structure:

`__init__.py
file_a.py
file_b.py`

Oh, sorry for past answer, go ahead and name it `__main__.py`.

You need `from . import foo` or `from . import *` when the `__init__.py` file is present. Then you can import anything from the same folder.

Comment: i tried those, from classmodule import MyClass + import classmodule MyClass('Thomas')