# Tensorflow.keras.layers "unresolved reference" in pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I just installed tensorflow, and am trying to get the basics to work. However, the import statement is underlined in red, with message "unresolved reference 'layers' ". The code does run correctly though.

I've tried some of the suggestions in this question: [PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code).

However, that question is not about my specific error, and I'm wondering what the cause of my error is, and whether it is just part of a pycharm-level bug, or something related to tensorflow.

My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf;
from tensorflow.keras import layers;
```

It gives the error "unresolved reference 'layers' " on a red jagged underline beneath "layers", with no indication of how to solve it.

Comment: it's not an error firstly, just pycharm's  not recognizing..

Comment: Same here. It's a really annoying bug and I find it crazy that such problems exist with tensorflow.

Comment: Check this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/76585492/12173531

Answer (score 5):

#### Pycharm may `just recognize the sub-package`

(1) `package tensorflow's structure :`

```
  ├── tensorflow
        ├── _api
        ├── compiler
        ├── contrib
        ├── core
        ├── examples
        ├── include
        ├── python
        ├── tools
        └── __init__.py
```

you can import the layer in an absolutely way

`from tensorflow._api.v1.keras import layers`

then you will get `no unresolved reference mark` in your pycharm.

(2) in package tensorflow's  `__init__.py`

```py
...
from tensorflow._api.v1 import keras  

# import all packages you want to use in tensorflow level 
# so, you can use `from tensorflow.keras import layers` for keras having been imported

...
```

then, you can simplely import `layers` like `from tensorflow.keras import layers`

But package `keras` is not the sub-package of `tensorflow`, so pycharm marked it as `unresolved reference`, which was not a error

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Tensorflow 2.0, try using this code to load them instead using 'from' and 'import'

```
import tensorflow
example_model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()
BatchNormalization = tensorflow.keras.layers.BatchNormalization
Conv2D = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D
MaxPooling2D = tensorflow.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D
Activation = tensorflow.keras.layers.Activation
Flatten = tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten
Dropout = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout
Dense = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense

##Testing Purpose On PyCharm##
example_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(100, 100, 1)))
example_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
example_model.add(Flatten())
example_model.summary()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can import the package directly with:

```
from keras import layers;
```

There is no need to add "import tensorflow as tf;" and "tensorflow" in the second line.

Comment: We're using the TensorFlow Keras implementation. So the code calls tf.keras and not the Keras API in itself.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in pycharm:

```
import tensorflow as tf
layers, models = tf.keras.layers, tf.keras.models
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Keras version 2.13.1 alone module without tensorflow and I found that I must put an `src` in import path of convolutional in Pycharm to easily import Conv1D like below:

```
from keras.src.layers.convolutional.conv1d import Conv1D
from keras.src.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
```

instead of:

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
```

I dont know why did the developers do this?!:)

Answer (score -1):

I just ran in Pycharm

pip install keras

Everything is solved