# Getting "Unresolved reference 'tensorflow'" error even after installing the tensorflow package

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am learning Machine Learning by following Google's Machine Learning Recipe videos on YouTube. I am using PyCharm and Anaconda. Right now, I am facing an issue while following this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSKfRcEDGUs&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIIuiBfYad6rFYQU_jL2ryal&index=6

I have installed tensorflow using the following command:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

But still, I am getting `Unresolved reference 'tensorflow'` error. Here are my codes:

```
from sklearn import metrics, model_selection
from tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib impor learn


def main(unused_argv):
    #load dataset.
    iris = learn.datasets.load_dataset('iris')
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(
        iris.data, iris.target, test_size = 0.2, random_stage=42)

    #Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively
    classifier = learn.DNNCClassifier(hidden_units=[10,20,10], n_classes=3)

    #Fit and predict.
    classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, steps = 200)
    score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, classifier.predict(x_test))
    print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(score))
```

What should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Should that "impor" in line 3 be "import"?

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Yes. But it doesn't fix the issue. Still getting the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686336/tensorflow-keras-layers-unresolved-reference-in-pycharm check this once.