# What is the PEP8 style recommendation for importing local functions?

Tags: python, pep8, zen-of-python

PEP8 dictates that you put your imports at the top of your code, which allows
the reader to see what you are importing in one space.

However if you have a local repo for functions in order to import them you must first change your current directory.

If you try to change your directory then you get a PEP8 violation because your imports aren't all in one place

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

sys.path.insert(0, r'local\path')

from local_functions import function_1
```

I understand that "A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds" and if I have to deal with a PEP8 violation that's okay.

I just imagine there is an actual solution to this as lots of people must be writing functions and importing them.

Is there a way to import locally stored functions that doesn't create a PEP8 violation?

Edit:
As noted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53832780/9936329

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
from local_functions import function_1  # noqa: E402
```

Will note that you are intentionally breaking PEP8 and also not inspect for unresolved references.

Comment: Why not make a package and install it locally with `pip`? That way you do not have to switch `paths` or anything like that.

Comment: Is this going to hit production? If so, I think it is not a good practice.

Comment: @Nishant what would you recommend as best practice?

Comment: highly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: you shouldn't be doing this in the first place. the simplest workaround is to invoke your script using `PYTHONPATH=. python my_program.py` or to make and install a local package.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the circumstances, but if it is only to satisfy the linter, you could maybe place your import in a try/except block?

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

try:
    from local_functions import function_1
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    sys.path.insert(0, r'local\path')
    from local_functions import function_1
```

Alternatively, you could use relative, or absolute imports, giving the location of your module relative to your project folder, or the absolute path on your HD.

Comment: This does satisfy the linter, as you say. But it seems like a workaround rather than "good code" that PEP8 tries to enforce. I think those saying to make a package might be the best option? But again it doesn't feel that clean.

Comment: agreed - Alternatively, you could use relative, or absolute imports, giving the location of your module relative to your project folder, or the absolute path on your HD.