# Pycharm visual warning:unresolved attribute reference

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Everything works fine,but warnings are always a bad mark that IDE points to.. so, I want to learn how to improve my coding to overcome warnings

I have a class and the methods as following:

```
from groupby import Groupby
import numpy as np,pandas as pd
class Plotly_Plots:
    def Weather_Plots(dbconnection):
        df1 = pd.read_sql('select * from weather_details', dbconnection)
        df = pd.read_sql('select * from crop_data', dbconnection)
        bigdata = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
        uniquevil = pd.DataFrame(bigdata.village.dropna().unique(), columns=['village'])
        con = pd.concat([uniquevil, df1['humidity'], df1['windspeed']], axis=1)
        fill = np.random.choice(con.village.dropna(), int(con.village.isna().sum()))
        con.loc[con.village.isna(), 'village'] = fill
        groupbyvalue='village'
        fieldstoaggregate='humidity'
        df=con
        return Groupby.groupby_agg(df,groupbyvalue,fieldstoaggregate)
```

groupby.py:

```
class Groupby():
    def groupby_agg(df,groupbyvalue,fieldstoaggregate):
        datamin = df.loc[df.groupby([groupbyvalue])[fieldstoaggregate].idxmin()]
        datamax = df.loc[df.groupby([groupbyvalue])[fieldstoaggregate].idxmax()]
        return plotsview.weatherplot(datamin, datamax)
```

I am seeing this warning at `loc` and `groupby` as unsolved attribute refernce `loc`,`groupby` for class `Groupby`

I guess my approach is not valid to do so,how can I improve my code to overcome those warnings

sorry,I am just into classes and methods in python!!

Comment: "I have a class and the methods" You have functions inside non-functional classes with no attributes. Do you have an actual problem with methods and classes -- or with PyCharm not recognising members of the ``pandas`` module?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi , I think the more I am worried is about methods and classes , as you mentioned it clearly ` functions inside non-functional classes with no attributes`, How can i make the whole stuff with a class and methods? The thing I am doing is converting a sql to dataframe and some operations and later I want to groupby (as groupby would be a common operation I wanted to be in separate reusable code)  also sql to dataframe would be same for all,.....can this be achieved with a class and methods or simply what I tried would be enough ?

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm seems not to recognize pandas package hence the errors.

Try invalidating caches:

File -> Invalidate Caches and restart IDE.

This question is possible duplicate of [PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code?rq=1)