# PyCharm Django docker-compose unresolved reference model

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, pycharm

I try config debug django project in pycharm by remote interpreter. My setup and debug completed. But in IDE always show error in line import models. Other import from django or anything else from library is normal.

[image]

I try add `__init__.py` in folder `gene`, invalidate cache.... many way so not work.
My question is: how to fix it? I used Pycharm Pro 2019.3, python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Setting the project root as suggested ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28696003)) did resolve the issue for me.
[image]

Comment: make root directory one level inside, its seem ok.
But it not resolve my problem.