# Unresolved reference flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Pycharm, with python 3.8 and I am watching a flask tutorial for beginners. this means that I am a beginner so I might not understand every vocab or solution, however, a little research on my end will make it alright.

So the problem I am having is that I downloaded flask_sqlalchemy with the following code on the PyCharm terminal:

```
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

I thought I had been successful since the event log also said installation successful. However, when I wrote the following code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

it reported "unresolved reference flask_sqlalchemy"

I then tried entering this in the terminal thinking it would work:

```
pip install -U Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

Nothing changed.

I tried installing SQLAlchemy to see if it would do something but it didn't. 
I used the following code in the terminal:

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Python Interpreter. Hit the plus button and install the package `SQLAlchemy`.

If that does not work, go to File -> Invalidate Cache.

What finally worked for me was deleting the `venv` folder, deleting the interpreter, and creating a new one. Make sure to enable inheritance of global packages because when you use `pip3 install Flask-SQLAlchemy` it installs to the default interpreter.

You really should be able to install it to your virtual environment. But I spent 3hrs on it and couldn't figure out how.

If you're still stuck, refer to ["Python shows unresolved references error for valid code.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11773462/4777844)