# I keep getting the "Unresolved reference" error when I use kivy properties in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to coding and do not understand why I keep get this error when I use kivy properties

PyCharm Community 2021.1.3

Kivy 2.0.0

```js
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
```

Comment: Does the program run fine? If yes, all this means is that pycharm isn't clever enough to resolve the reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many solutions to this, some more convenient than others, and they don't always work.

```
File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter 
> Select "No interpreter" in the "Project interpreter" list 
> Apply > Set your python interpreter again > Click Apply
```

Here's all you can try, going from 'quick' to 'annoying':

Do File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart and restart PyCharm.
You could also do this after any of the below methods, just to be sure.
First, check which interpreter you're running: Run -> Edit Configurations -> Configuration -> Python Interpreter.

Refresh the paths of your interpreter:
File -> Settings
Project: [name] -> Project Interpreter -> 'Project Interpreter': Gear icon -> More...
Click the 'Show paths' button (bottom one)
Click the 'Refresh' button (bottom one)

Remove the interpreter and add it again:
File -> Settings
Project: [name] -> Project Interpreter -> 'Project Interpreter': Gear icon -> More...
Click the 'Remove' button
Click the 'Add' button and re-add your interpeter

Delete your project preferences
Delete your project's .idea folder
Close and re-open PyCharm
Open your project from scratch

Delete your PyCharm user preferences (but back them up first).
~/.PyCharm50 on Mac
%homepath%/.PyCharm50 on Windows
Switch to another interpreter, then back again to the one you want.
Create a new virtual environment, and switch to that environments' interpreter.
Switch to another interpreter altogether, don't switch back.

If you are using Docker, take note:

Make sure you are using pip3 not pip, especially with remote docker and docker-compose interpreters.
Avoid influencing PYTHONPATH. More info here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000058690-Module-not-found-in-PyCharm-but-externally-in-Python

Comment: hey, if you copy someone's work, give him some credit at least... https://stackoverflow.com/a/35896895/4034593