# How to import a class object from a project that is in different folder in Python using ide pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

my project directory looks like this

```
-- PycharmProjects   #foldrname
     - imp_func      #foldrname
            - funcs.py  #having a class name "specs"  
     - project1      #foldrname
            - projct.py
```

I want to import class "specs" which is in funcs.py into projct.py

Code tried:

```
 from PycharmProjects.imp_func.funcs import specs   # UnResolved reference PycharmProjects
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28696003)

Answer (score 0):

Oops... Python packages are indeed represented as subdirectories, but not all directories are packages! The `from x import y` only makes sense if `x` is a python module or a Python package **and** if it is accessible from the Python path.

Here the correct way would be to put the `imp_func` folder in the Python path, for example by putting it into the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Then you will be able to use:

```
from funcs import specs
```